# React Native: run-ios has stopped working (ReferenceError)

Tags: ios, react-native, referenceerror

I've run into an issue when running the `run-ios` command. Prior to now, the app started up fine, but now I'm running into this screen before the app even finishes bundling.

Here's a link to the screen I'm getting: https://d17oy1vhnax1f7.cloudfront.net/items/1J3n3u1z3w2k2E160V1B/Screen%20Shot%202017-01-18%20at%2010.36.08%20AM.png?v=783d1021

Here are some of the steps I've gone through to debug the problem:

- Reset the cache on startup with `npm start --reset-cache`
- Cleared the watchman config
- Enabled remote debugging to pause on caught exceptions*
- Created a new branch for a previous commit that I know had worked prior to this issue (no resolution)
- Removed and reinstalled my `node_modules` folder
- Removed and reinstalled watchman through homebrew
- Cleared npm cache
- Upgraded react-native to `0.40.0`

*This is the line where the error is catching on when inspecting in chrome:

```
global = DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope {console: Object, __fbBatchedBridgeConfig: Object, __DEV_
```

I've tried a number of solutions in a number of issues but haven't been able to come up with the right solution.

Here's some possibly relevant information:

`run-ios` startup log:

```
Found Xcode project TipHiveMobile.xcodeproj
Launching iPhone 6 (iOS 10.2)...
Building using "xcodebuild -project TipHiveMobile.xcodeproj -   configuration Debug -scheme TipHiveMobile -destination id=DDBF9D1C-CB3F-   4FCF-B9B6-C7AF372B7F3E -derivedDataPath build"
User defaults from command line:

IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/tylerreckart/Code/tiphive/TipHiveMobile/ios/build


=== BUILD TARGET RNVectorIcons OF PROJECT RNVectorIcons WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
```

`log-ios` output on reload

```
Jan 18 10:45:05 Nosferatu logd[30752] <Notice>: metadata shared cached  uuid is null (using logd's shared cache info) nsurlstoraged (39014)

Jan 18 10:45:05 Nosferatu logd[30752] <Notice>: Failed to harvest strings for pathless uuid '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

Jan 18 10:45:15 Nosferatu TipHiveMobile[31100] <Notice>: Initializing <RCTBatchedBridge: 0x608000199300> (parent: <RCTBridge: 0x6000000a28e0>, executor: RCTWebSocketExecutor)

Jan 18 10:45:15 Nosferatu TipHiveMobile[31100] <Warning>: Required dispatch_sync to load constants for RCTSourceCode. This may lead to deadlocks

Jan 18 10:50:33 Nosferatu routined[30747] <Error>: CoreLocation: Error occurred while trying to retrieve motion state update: CMErrorDomain Code:104
```

- React Native version: 0.39.0
- Platform: iOS
- Operating System: MacOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel like a complete idiot, but the solution here was just to restart my computer. There must have been a leftover process running that was interfering with the way things were bundling.

For your entertainment: https://media.giphy.com/media/F7yLXA5fJ5sLC/giphy.gif

Answer (score 2):

Seems like we have a similar list of things we go through when you can't run the react-native app.

An additional thing I would try:

- Commit your changes in a branch to make sure you don't lose your changes
- Delete your entire folder: rm -rf
- Clone it again: git clone
- Re-install and run: npm install && react-native run-ios ...

This is the last thing I try, but it did work for me in the past.

Comment: Unfortunately, that hasn't worked either. I cloned the repository from a commit SHA that I know for a fact was working, but I'm still receiving the error. I think it has something to do with one of the modules, but I don't know for certain.